# Adding processing buffer output to QgsMapLayerRegistry (argument 1 has unexpected type 'dict')

Tags: pyqgis, buffer

I'm writing a qgis plugin which needs a fixed-distance-buffer algorithm and must add the buffer result to the map layers of the software.

I have the following code:

```
# these are my import list
import os.path

import qgis.core
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
import processing
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon
```

and the main part in run() method is:

```
    # region adding vector layers
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            layer_list.append(layer.name())
        else:
            break
    # region crime inputs and crime instance


    self.cInput = self.dlg.comboBox_input_Crime
    self.cInput.clear()
    self.cInput.addItems(layer_list)
```

after the if statement in run() method:

```
self.pic = self.cInput.currentIndex()
self.selectedCrime = layers[self.pic]
buff=  processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', layers[self.pic], 100, 50, False, None)
qgis.core.QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(buff)
```

now when I run my plugin, after a progress bar appears, it shows an error of `TypeError: QgsMapLayerRegistry.addMapLayer(QgsMapLayer, bool addToLegend=True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'dict'`!

please explain what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to load as a layer a vector object called buff.
As you can see in [the qgis:fixeddistancebuffer doc](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/fixeddistancebuffer.html#outputs) the output is dictionary with "OUTPUT" entry :

```
buff['OUTPUT']u'/var/folders/sr/g1qdy1dd5t57862r5yr0g4lc0000gn/T/processingbe0227f51efb4870b2f53dac7abc2c67/ccaa1966d99c4339ab669c9a76281cb4/OUTPUT.shp'
```

So when you try to load this vector as a layer with

```
qgis.core.QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(buff)
```

Python returns an exception cause [addMapLayer](http://qgis.sourceforge.net/qgis_api/html/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html#a3)() method is waiting for a [QgsMapLayer](http://qgis.sourceforge.net/qgis_api/html/classQgsMapLayer.html) class which could be a [vectorLayer](http://qgis.sourceforge.net/qgis_api/html/classQgsVectorLayer.html) in your case or rasterLayer as well.

so, create a new vectorLayer and populate it with your new shape OUTPUT and push it to your QgsMapLayerRegistry :

```
buffLyr =  QgsVectorLayer(buff['OUTPUT'], "buffer", "ogr")    
qgis.core.QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(buffLyr)
```

Comment: the solution above gives this error: `'TypeError: QgsVectorDataProvider.addFeatures(list-of-QgsFeature) -> (bool, list-of-QgsFeature): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'`

Comment: my fault. because you have only one buff feature, use addfeature instead of addfeatures. I edited the post

Comment: i'm sorry but it gives : `TypeError: QgsVectorLayer.addFeature(QgsFeature, bool alsoUpdateExtent=True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'dict' ` now.

Comment: I am sorry cause i didn't test on my side, I learned something that processing algorithm output are dict (as your error show). So i change again the code to feet your need and I tested this time, with a shorter code. according your code is correct this should work now, and I hope you will understand why.